# Empty props when I open a modal - React

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

In my parent component I have the following code:

```
    return (
        <div className={`${this.props.className}`}>
            <CreatePerson
                open={this.state.modalCreate}
                value={this.state.person}
                close={this.changeModalCreate}
            />

            <Grid>
                <Row className='custom-row'>
                    {PersonCards}
                </Row>

                <Button variant="fab" color="primary" aria-label="add" className='button-add' onClick={() => this.changeModalCreate()}>
                    <AddIcon />
                </Button>
            </Grid>
        </div>
    )
```

I want to put in the state of CreatePerson the value I am passing in the Props.

Before I click the button to open CreatePerson (it's a modal), with this constructor in CreatePerson, I have the following object:

[image]

The object has all the properties I need. But after clicking on the button to open the modal all props disappear, I get the following object:

[image]

(Constructor of CreatePerson)

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    console.log(props)
    this.state = {}

    this.addProfileImg = this.addProfileImg.bind(this);
    this.removeProfileImg = this.removeProfileImg.bind(this);
    this.addBackgroundImg = this.addBackgroundImg.bind(this);
    this.removeBackgroundImage = this.removeBackgroundImage.bind(this);
    this.addInput = this.addInput.bind(this);
    this.updateText = this.updateText.bind(this);
}
```

Function that opens the modal

```
changeModalCreate() {
    this.setState((prevState) => ({ ...prevState, modalCreate: !prevState.modalCreate }))
}
```

Comment: We can't see the method that opens the modal. Maybe we need to see `changeModalCreate`. Can you add a simple CodeSandbox example link? https://codesandbox.io/s/new

Comment: I added the function in question

Comment: How is `this.state.person` modified in the parent componet? a handler for the modifications occuring in `<CreatePerson .... />`?

Comment: No, is a static object that stays in the parent state

Comment: I want to use this object in the child element